# question about $\ell^p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

This is an exercise of an old test of functional analysis

**Let $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $(y_n)$ a numerical sequence such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n<\infty$ for all $(x_n)\in\ell^p$. Show that $(y_n)\in\ell^q$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Hint: Put $\varphi_j(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^j x_n y_n$ .**

From the hint I can get the $\varphi_j$ are in $(\ell^p)^*=\ell^q$ and converges to $\varphi(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n<\infty$ and $\varphi$ also lies on $\ell^q$ but i can't say why $(y_n)\in\ell^q$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2782337, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/260970, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183684  – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cvarphi_j(x)%3D%5Cdisplaystyle%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5Ej%20x_n%20y_n%24)

Comment: yes! thank you very much